# É possível criar uma funcionalidade para alertar que uma pergunta foi excluída / respondida durante a edição?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto

Passei por uma situação bem chata agora há pouco...

Passei uma hora e dez criando uma resposta para uma pergunta do @bigown, e quando cliquei em "Publique sua resposta", tive a triste decepção de ter sido proibido de submeter a resposta, pois a pergunta havia sido excluída enquanto eu criava uma resposta.

Existe uma forma de alertar a pessoa que está respondendo que uma pergunta foi excluída, ou que uma nova resposta foi criada para a pergunta, sem que a pessoa tenha que dar um *scroll* para a parte superior da tela, e sem que a pessoa tenha que clicar no botão "Publique sua resposta"?

Comment: Você perdeu a resposta? Antes de o bigown excluir, a pergunta foi fechada como duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11378/prefira-composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-vez-de-heran%C3%A7a. Você ainda pode postar sua resposta lá ou em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/%C3%89-errado-usar-heran%C3%A7a-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns, onde achar mais adequado.

Comment: Ainda tenho a resposta em um notepad. Vou publicar lá apenas para não deixá-la perdida... se bem que as respostas dessas duas perguntas já estão bem completas e com alto nível :) Mas essa funcionalidade realmente seria útil ;)

Comment: Eu *acho* que o sistema já notifica fechamento, edição e exclusão, mas como você disse, é no topo. Se você rolou a página, o único indício é que o conteúdo "pula" um pouco pra baixo. Realmente não é o ideal.

Comment: Isso! Ele cria um texto lá em cima, mas quem está lá embaixo e estava olhando para a tela quando o texto foi criado (perdendo o "pulo") fica sem saber.

Comment: Não sabia disto. Desculpe o transtorno. Mas era necessário. De qualquer forma você conseguiu aproveitá-la. A resposta é muito boa mesmo. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21891/101

Comment: @bigown Valeu, mesmo!!! Não foi transtorno nenhum, porque eu iria deixar guardada para a próxima vez ;) Mas aproveitei a ocasião para levantar a questão. Acho que o alerta poderia ser algo mais visível, quiçá, até mais invasivo, mesmo :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn No caso de deleção, poderia ser ao mesmo uma troca da cor de fundo do campo de resposta pro "vermelho-delete". Assim você poderia tomar uma providência sem perder o conteúdo. Triste mesmo é estar com uma baita resposta, e sem querer dar um tab sem perceber, e um backspace em seguida, o que não é nada difícil ao editar código :) (em alguns casos o autosave da SE ajuda, mas nao é sempre que funciona)

Comment: @Bacco sim! O vermelho é genial! E o backspace também seria catastrófico :D Para ser honesto, nunca tive curiosidade em testar se existe algo como uma msg no "window.unload()" te impedindo de sair da página durante a edição (sempre tive medo em perder o que estava sendo editado :P)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn o ideal é salvar com timer ou avaliar mudanças a cada tantos caracteres de diferença. Apenas unload não adianta, pois podem acontecer _crashes_, queda de energia, encerramento da tarefa na marra, e assim vai.

Comment: @Bacco concordo! Acho que me expressei mal no outro comentário... O unload é só mesmo para mostrar uma mensagenzinha, o save tem mesmo que ser "*as you go*" ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn eu que "li mal". Você foi claro em "'window.unload()' te impedindo de sair da página", mas eu estava com a mente no _autosave_. Em resumo: vamos continuar salvando externamente por enquanto :D